# Doctrine2 @ORM in entity mapping annotation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

i am new to Doctrine2 and have created entitie-classes from my existing database using the following command:

```
.\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database annotation ./EXPORT/
```

Now i have my Classes and they are looking like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity; // this line was not generated automatically

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Category
 {

     /**
     * @ORM\var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
     private $id;
 ....
```

Looks good, but i dont understand why there is "@ORM\" used before every notation in the docblocks.
When i create queries they don't work until i remove this "@ORM\" bevore every notation.
Did i miss something?
I am not using any framework (Zend/Symfony...). I am just using "doctrine/orm": "~2.4" with composer.

Best regards
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ORM refers to the namespace shortcut at the top

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

E.g. you could also use the Id annotation with the full namespace like that:

```
/**
* @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id 
*/
```

Besides that I would recommend to take a look at the annotation docs to get doctrine running correctly

(http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html and
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, but i still dont understand why i would need the Doctrine\ORM\Mapping namespace. My query:
$qb
            ->select('c.name, c.description')
            ->from('App\Model\Entity\Category', 'c');
returns everything it should when i remove the ORM-namespace from the annotations and stops working when this namespace is there. Could you explain why this is the case? Till then i will go through the documentation you have sent once again, maybe i missed something...

Comment: I probably should read the error messages more carefully. I have found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099060/doctrine2-class-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class